# simplify json array to different variables depending on groups

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json output from php file like following;

```
[{"device_id":"9700001","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:49:06"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:47:05"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:45:05"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:24:57"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:22:57"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:20:56"},
{"device_id":"9700001","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:18:56"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:16:56"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:14:56"}]
```

I want to convert this array to particular dataset i.e. I want to get values of device 9700001 of update_time and the sensor value to two datasets ,
for 9700001,

```
datasensor1=[{"sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:49:06"},{"sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:18:56"},{"sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:18:56"}]
```

for device 9700002 ,

```
 datasensor2=[{"sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:47:05"},{"sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:22:57"},{"sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:16:56"},{"sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:14:56"}]
```

similarly for device 9700003,

```
 datasensor3=[{"sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:45:05"},{"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:24:57"},{"sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:20:56"}]
```

I tired first to group by device_id using

```
 var sensor= _.groupBy(data,"device_id");
```

but I am not able to separate the object afterwards. How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `filter()` and `map()`:

```js
var data = [{"device_id":"9700001","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:49:06"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:47:05"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:45:05"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:24:57"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:22:57"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:20:56"},
{"device_id":"9700001","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:18:56"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:16:56"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:14:56"}];

var sorted = {};
data.forEach((row) => {
 sorted[row.device_id] = [];
});
Object.keys(sorted).forEach((id) => {
  sorted[id] = data.filter((row) => row.device_id === id).map((row) => ({
    sensor_value: row.sensor_value,
    update_time: row.update_time
  }));
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

try with [`Array#reduce`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiR7oKOoJ_UAhVKL48KHaMfDrEQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FReduce&usg=AFQjCNG5y6qS8juF9mnkgIEZQgeRUeoJ3A&sig2=YRLMdUdIlGdRRRwdEt5M1Q) method

```js
var data =[{"device_id":"9700001","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:49:06"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:47:05"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"31.5","update_time":"2017-04-28 18:45:05"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:24:57"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:22:57"},
{"device_id":"9700003","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:20:56"},
{"device_id":"9700001","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:18:56"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:16:56"},
{"device_id":"9700002","sensor_value":"33.1","update_time":"2017-04-28 06:14:56"}]

function group(data , id){
return data.reduce((a,b)=>{
if(b.device_id == id)
a.push({
sensor_value:b.sensor_value,
update_time:b.update_time
})
return a
},[])
}
console.log(group(data,9700001))
console.log(group(data,9700002))
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.how do I make this dynamic. I mean depending on number of device_id's  I should able to create datasets.